# Maximum Entropy with no index

Tags: entropy, bernoulli-distribution, maximum-entropy

This is a simpler problem than trying to solve, but have a feeling once get the methodology I can apply it to the harder problem.

Let

$ H(p)= -q \ln(q) - p \ln(p) $

be the entropy of the Bernoulli distribution with $q=1-p$

I am trying to maximize the sum of the entropies

$ E(P) = \sum_{i \mathop =1}^n H(p_i)$

Given

$ \sum_{i \mathop =1}^n p_i =A$

$ \sum_{i \mathop =1}^n p_i^2 =B$

Notice that each $p_i$ independently can be between $(0,1)$. When I set up the Lagragian, and took the derivative with respect to $p_i$, there was no index or anything differentiating $p_i$ from $p_j$ (e.g. a weight $w_i$). If the set $\{P\}$ is a solution than any permutation of $\{P\}$ is also a solution. Order does not matter.

Is there a way to solve for any instance of set of $\{P\}$ which yields a maximum sum of entropies?

(The harder problem just need the value of maximum $E(P)$ , and not the value of $p_i$ themselves, but have a feeling must solve for the set first)